# How to add a second root element?

Tags: django, django-treebeard

I have the model:

```
from treebeard.ns_tree import NS_Node
class Category(NS_Node):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    node_order_by = ['id']

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

and i try create new root element:

```
>>>from index.models import Category
>>>get = lambda node_id: Category.objects.get(pk=node_id)
>>>last_root = Category.get_last_root_node()
>>>get(last_root.pk).add_sibling(pos='sorted-sibling', name='ROOT2')
```

the following error:

```
Exception Value:    
Cannot use None as a query value
Exception Location: e:\work\newsklad\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\query.py in prepare_lookup_value, line 995
```

how remove this bag?

Answer (score 0):

You should probably use use [NS_Node.add_root](https://tabo.pe/projects/django-treebeard/docs/tip/api.html#treebeard.models.Node.add_root), but your more immediate issue is that [`pos` is a positional argument](https://tabo.pe/projects/django-treebeard/docs/tip/api.html#treebeard.models.Node.add_sibling) not a keyword one.

```
get(last_root.pk).add_sibling('sorted-sibling', name='ROOT2')
```